# Combine two Java Objects in TEIID

Tags: java, sql, wildfly, teiid

I have a UDF that returns two java objects with double values:

```
object1 = {1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5}
object2 = {5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0}
```

I would like to combine/merge them in following way returning a double array:

```
resultArray = [1.0,5.0,1.5,6.0,2.0,7.0,2.5,8.0]
```

I have looked in to arrayiterate to return table format and then array_agg to combine the two but I have not been successful with this approach.

Appreciate if I can get some assistance and guidance on what would be the fastest way to get the desired resultArray

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use ARRAYTABLE, then you join those two tables.

Comment: I tried ARRAYTABLE, it only gets me first value in array not the entire array in tabular format:

`SELECT x.* FROM dataTable, ARRAYTABLE(getObject(dataTable.data,1))
COLUMNS doubleArray double) AS x`

the UDF retrieves object arrays this way:

`object1: getObject(dataTable.data,1)
object2: getObject(dataTable.data,2)`

Comment: The following works BUT only for first values in each array, how can I combine multiple values:

`SELECT array_agg(x.object1||','||y.object2) FROM dataTable , 
ARRAYTABLE(getObject(dataTable.data,1)) COLUMNS object1 double ) AS x,
ARRAYTABLE(getObject(dataTable.data,2)) COLUMNS object2 double ) AS y`

Comment: you can do something like  ` ARRAYTABLE(dataTable.object1, COLUMNS col1 double, row_number() over(order by col1) id) x` and create two virtual tables and then join by their id in a query